# How to share LWP::UserAgent object between threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, lwp-useragent

Is it possible to create a shared LWP::UserAgent object that can be used for HTTP requests in different threads?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to share it?

Comment: Let's imagine that I have several threads that wants to GET or POST some requests to the server over the HTTPS from time to time. Do I really need to create a private thread's copy of the LWP::UserAgent object for this purposes? What about cookies? I think there is some overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  There may be a way to use shared mem to achieve this, but even if it were possible, I don't think you'd want to do this because there are objects stored on the user agent itself such as last error etc.  If you want to synchronize cookies,  you can take care of that by specifying a cookie jar that you persist and reuse ( from perldoc for LWP::UserAgent ):

$ua->cookie_jar( $cookie_jar_obj )